# Why inheriting of C++ class from templated class and at the same time from abstract class results in duplication of class member?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I have following C++ code

Configuration.h

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t id;
  uint32_t data; 
} Config;
```

Handler.h

```
class HandlerBase
{
public:
    typedef void (*func_ptr)(void *data);
    
    HandlerBase(func_ptr function) : function(function) {}
    
private:
    func_ptr function;
};

template<class T>
class Handler : public HandlerBase
{
public:
    Handler() : HandlerBase(&fun_01) {}
    
private:
    static void fun_01(void *data) {}
};
```

AbstractBase.h

```
class AbstractBase
{
public:    
  virtual void method_01() = 0;
  virtual void method_02() = 0;
};
```

A.h

```
#include "AbstractBase.h"
#include "Handler.h"
#include "Configuration.h"

class A : public Handler<A>, public AbstractBase
{
    public:
      A();       
      void method_01();
      void method_02();
     
    private:
       Config cfg;   
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

A::A() {}     
void A::method_01() {}        
void A::method_02() {}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    A a;
        
    return 0;
}
```

In case I have steped through the code in the debugger I have noticed that whenever I create the `a` instance of the `A` class in the `main` the `a` instance contains two instances of the `cfg` struct. Here is the output of my debugger (I have been using the GDB along with the g++ compiler (v 4.6.3) under Netbeans IDE v8.2. under Windows 10 Pro)

[image]

**EDIT_01:**
I have found that I can store values only into one of the `cfg` instances. After assignment into the struct items

```
cfg.id = 0x55;
cfg.data = 0xAAAAAAAA;
```

I can see follwing content of the `cfg` structs

[image]

In case I observe the content of the memory at address `0xffffcbd0` (content of the `this` pointer) I see following (one byte of `id` item with three padding bytes followed by four bytes of the `data` item)

[image]

**EDIT_02:**

I have added below given method into the `A` class

```
void A::init()
{
    cfg.id = 0x55;
    cfg.data = 0xAAAAAAAA;
}
```

and modified the `method_01` in following manner

```
void A::method_01() 
{
    if ((cfg.data == 0xAAAAAAAA) && (cfg.id == 0x55)) {
        std::cout << "Config ok!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The `main.cpp`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        
    A a;
    a.init();
    a.method_01();
            
    return 0;
}
```

prints the `Config ok!` message.

At the same time only one instance of `cfg` struct is created in case the `A` class inherits only from the `Handler`. Please can anybody tell me what is the reason for this behavior? Is there any way how to avoid this duplication of the class member? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think it has 2 instances. Specifically what do you see in the debugger which makes you think this?

Comment: You may need to use virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Mike Vine thank you for your reaction. It is based on my observation that under the `this` pointer of the instance of the `A` class I see two `cfg` structs.

Comment: You are probably interpreting it wrong - can you update your question which exactly what the debugger shows. If its a command line debugger then include the text, else include a picture.

Comment: There is no hidden second cfg: https://godbolt.org/z/s1h3jG . You likely interpreted what you saw wrong.

Comment: this might be a rare case, where including a picture is not only appropriate, but necessary to understand the quesiton, because most certainly there is no second `cfg` member, but its hard to know why you think there is one

Comment: It may be an artifact of your debugger.   Here is a godbolt project  with your code, where you can play with sizeof(Config), by adding data to it: https://godbolt.org/z/Kzvb6e  .  class A is consistently 8 bytes larger than sizeof(Config) + sizeof(HandlerBase), which sounds right.  sizeof(A) is not twice sizeof(Config).   Which debugger are you using?

Comment: @DanM.  Thanks for that neat trick with -fdump-record-layouts.  I've learned something useful today :)

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I have just updated my original question.

Comment: @ProfessorJimatura   Have you tried using sizeof() and varying the size of Config to confirm there are indeed 2 cfg structs?   Add and array of 128 bytes to Configuration and double check.  I have not been able to generate a second cfg member... I've tried gcc and clang.  Debugger bugs and artefact _are_ a thing.  Can you store different values in the 2 `cfg` data members you are seeing?

Comment: What platform, OS, compiler, gdb version? What do you see when you expand the two `cfg`s?

Comment: Your GUI wrapper around `gdb`, or possibly the ancient `gdb` you are using, is buggy. The up to date version of `gdb` by doesn't show any such thing.